# move apps to internal memory from system memory?

Tags: insufficient-memory

I have LG e405. How do i get downloaded apps /any app from system/phone memory to goto internal memory?there are heaps more that i need to know but most apps and things seem to have disappeared from phone , now no room to reinstall them? This 3rd or 4th time has happened. Ok will not be far away, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into your application manager in the settings. Clicking on each individual app will bring up the status and information screen for that app. Some apps will have the option to 'Move To External Storage'. Press that and let it do its thing and the app will be on your SD Card.

Keep in mind that not all apps can be moved to external storage. This is a specific functionality of applications. You'll find fairly regularly that applications do not have the move functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean internal memory as in the internal sd card, you can use the app manager option in settings to do it, unless your phone ships with merged storage. In that case, you will need to root and use a dedicated app like Link2SD to move apps to the external inserted microSD card.

Comment: Hello that i am getting to but i have to add 2nd partition?? I also need to.root? My ph but so far unlucky. got "link2sd" now but supose toupdate"link2sd

Comment: Sorry,i think i messed up somehow but trying again.That i am doing/trying now.seems i need 2nd partition and to be rooted?which i have not figured out how to do yet? The apps so far,move2sd,link2sd card,1more?.was stuff that just dissappeared?along with an unroot your ph, app??anyway i thankyou ,now I've link2sd but seems i need to update (thanks google shop?) Wish had known before,link2sd + is able to move apps without root ? So will give things ago and see and thanks for help let you know how it goes,

Comment: No. Link2sd needs root.